# Selenium-webdriver - how to pass a value in "TO" field

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send email from rediffmail, but it failed to pass values in the "TO" field. Here is my code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login1")).sendKeys("abcd");
    driver.findElement(By.name("passwd")).sendKeys("*****");
    driver.findElement(By.name("proceed")).click();

    // compose

    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"boxscroll\"]/li[1]/a").click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys("xyz");
```

How can I pass a value to the "TO" field?

Comment: Why are you using actions to sendkeys , and not element.sendkeys

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are identifying the TO field , once you successfully find and make it active, do the below steps.

Replace

```
action.sendKeys("xyz")
```

With

```
action.sendKeys("xyz").perform()
```

Comment: Cursor is already at TO field so i think there is no need to locate web element                   
                                                                                                                                      and this script also not working.....action.sendKeys("xyz").perform()